# Unable to install pymunk with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pymunk

I'm trying to install pymunk but doing `pip install pymunk` gives me an error. The README file says this on Innstallation:

In the normal case pymunk can be installed with pip:

```
> pip install pymunk
```

It has one direct dependency, CFFI.

Pymunk can also be installed with conda, from the conda-forge channel:

```
> conda install -c conda-forge pymunk
```

This is the error I get:

```
Collecting pymunk
Using cached pymunk-5.6.0.zip (5.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.13.1 in c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pymunk) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.13.1->pymunk) (2.19)
Building wheels for collected packages: pymunk
  Building wheel for pymunk (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EMMSCH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qebhmk1e\\pymunk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EMMSCH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qebhmk1e\\pymunk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\EMMSCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-07rt65wo'
       cwd: C:\Users\EMMSCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qebhmk1e\pymunk\
  Complete output (61 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\arbiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\autogeometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\bb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\body.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\collision_handler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\constraint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\contact_point_set.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\kivy_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\matplotlib_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\pygame_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\pyglet_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\query_info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\shapes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\shape_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\space_debug_draw_options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\vec2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi_abi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\_libload.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  copying pymunk\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunkoptions
  copying pymunkoptions\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunkoptions
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_arbiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_autogeometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_bb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_body.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_constraint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_shape.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_shape_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\test_vec2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  copying pymunk\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
  running egg_info
  writing pymunk.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pymunk.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to pymunk.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to pymunk.egg-info\top_level.txt
  Running on Windows. GCC will be forced used
  reading manifest file 'pymunk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'examples\.ipynb_checkpoints'
  writing manifest file 'pymunk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  Could not detect if on Android. Defaulting to false.
  cc -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -g -DCP_USE_CGPOINTS=0 -DNDEBUG -shared -O3 -m64 -Ichipmunk_src\include -c chipmunk_src\src\chipmunk.c -o chipmunk_src\src\chipmunk.o
  error: command 'cc' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymunk
  Running setup.py clean for pymunk
Failed to build pymunk
Installing collected packages: pymunk
    Running setup.py install for pymunk ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EMMSCH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qebhmk1e\\pymunk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EMMSCH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qebhmk1e\\pymunk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\EMMSCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0q5_wkzu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pymunk'
         cwd: C:\Users\EMMSCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qebhmk1e\pymunk\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\arbiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\autogeometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\bb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\body.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\collision_handler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\constraint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\contact_point_set.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\kivy_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\matplotlib_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\pygame_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\pyglet_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\query_info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\shapes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\shape_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\space_debug_draw_options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\vec2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi_abi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\_libload.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    copying pymunk\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunkoptions
    copying pymunkoptions\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunkoptions
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_arbiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_autogeometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_bb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_body.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_constraint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_shape.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_shape_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\test_vec2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    copying pymunk\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pymunk\tests
    running egg_info
    writing pymunk.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pymunk.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pymunk.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pymunk.egg-info\top_level.txt
    Running on Windows. GCC will be forced used
    reading manifest file 'pymunk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples\.ipynb_checkpoints'
    writing manifest file 'pymunk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    Could not detect if on Android. Defaulting to false.
    cc -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -g -DCP_USE_CGPOINTS=0 -DNDEBUG -shared -O3 -m64 -Ichipmunk_src\include -c chipmunk_src\src\chipmunk.c -o chipmunk_src\src\chipmunk.o
    error: command 'cc' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EMMSCH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qebhmk1e\\pymunk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EMMSCH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qebhmk1e\\pymunk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\EMMSCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0q5_wkzu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\emmsch001\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pymunk' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I fix/work around this?

Comment: The compilation fails, but there should be a `whl` on pypi for your platform. Can you post the output of running `python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())"` in your cmd?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vUijxacq

Comment: Can you try to download [the whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/85/adc32a0551d272768d4ea02b6840e287ece2186eb88a747a3868ced7d9bc/pymunk-5.6.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl) manually and then do `pip install <whl-file>`

Comment: This worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear, I have no idea why `pip install pymunk` did not download and install the `whl` file in the first place though